# best practice for generate laravel request validation in rest api app

Tags: laravel, request, restful-authentication

i have a restful app with laravel 5.5 and i am using laravel request class for validating requests before use theme in my controllers.
so now i have many request class because there is one class for each action. for example loginRequest.php for login action and RegisterRequest.php for register and ....
I am wondering if it is ok to produce requests in this way!
i have five request just for AuthController and much more requests for other controller!
I can't merge them because of individual rules belongs to each one.
so what is the best practice to handle this volume of requests?

Comment: It's better to use the Request and the validator validate form fields. They are mostly used in conjunction with forms that will be saving information to your database and you can validate them to ensure integrity. Having 5 requests for one controller is not that uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

i use this solution
this trait and you can use 1 request for all method
[ResourceRules](https://github.com/The-Hasanov/ResourceRules/blob/master/src/ResourceRules.php)

Comment: i forget update github version but old version also can help you